# Comprobar si una persona esta agregada en una tabla SQLite con Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

estoy tratando de consultar a una tabla el nombre de una persona con el dni, si esta agregado en la tabla, no tengo ningún problema, pero si no lo esta, me sale un nullPointerException, y no se como validar para que si no esta registrado en la tabla, me bote un mensaje de usuario no registrado.
El Select:

```
fun selectPersonal(idcodigogeneral: String): TrabajadorModel? {
    var item: TrabajadorModel? = null

    val db:SQLiteDatabase = helper?.readableDatabase!!

    val columnas = arrayOf(
        tareoContract.Companion.personalContract.IDCODIGOGENERAL,
        tareoContract.Companion.personalContract.TRABAJADOR
    )

    val c: Cursor = db.query(

        tareoContract.Companion.personalContract.TBL_PERSONAL,
        columnas,
        "IDCODIGOGENERAL = ?",
        arrayOf(idcodigogeneral),
        null,
        null,
        null
    )
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            item =
                TrabajadorModel(
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.personalContract.IDCODIGOGENERAL)),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.personalContract.TRABAJADOR))
                )

        }
        c.close()

        return item

}
```

Y aqui uso la función:

```
    fun getTrabajador(dni: String):Boolean{

    if (tcrud.selectPersonal(dni)!!.equals(null)){
        val personalR = tcrud.selectPersonal(dni)
        Log.d("Error:: ", personalR.toString())
        val nombre = personalR!!.trabajador.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pre registro agregado trabajador: " + nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Trabajador no registrado " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


        return true


}
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

[image: Error NullPointer]

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: prueba controlando exepciones try catch, no se como sera en kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Esta instrucción `tcrud.selectPersonal(dni)!!.equals(null)` está mal planteada.

Cuando usas `!!` estás diciéndole al compilador que no se preocupe porque la instancia nunca será `null`, el compilador no se quejará, pero si alguna vez resulta `null` se caerá el programa.

Haz el null check de esta otra forma:

```
val persona = tcrud.selectPersonal(dni)
if (persona != null) {
    ...
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Trabajador no registrado " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

O mejor aún:

```
tcrud.selectPersonal(dni)?.also { persona ->
    ...
} ?: Toast.makeText(this, "Trabajador no registrado " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Te sugiero usar lo menos posible valores `null` y "null checks" ya que Kotlin permite subsanar esas falencias que tienen otros lenguajes. En su lugar usa más "safe calls" y el operador "Elvis" `?:`.